# Match the expression using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a regex that can select the matches as shown here [enter link description here](https://regex101.com/r/CRR5zi/6)

```
\b(\w)[-'\w]* (?:[-",\/\\*&'\w]* ){1,}\(\1[A-Z]{1,}\)
```

But this will not select the connectors protocols(CP) i.e if there is no space between long form of the word and brackets. How do I make the regex to select the expressions with and also without space between brackets

However it must select both **connectors protocols{space}(CP)**  and **connectors protocols{no space}(CP)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple stupid (KISS).

```
\b(\w)[-'\w ]+\(\1[A-Z]+\)
```

To better handle cases like `standard that establishes specifications cables (SC)` and `so for instance secure socket layer (SSL)`, RegEx alone is not sufficient. Use the following script.

```js
const text = "The Universal Serial Bus (USB) is an industry standard that establishes specifications cables (SC) and connectors protocols(CP) whoa this is a for connection found (CF) Keep it simple stupid (KISS)! so for instance secure socket layer (SSL) Couldn't match start-of-frame (SOF) , start-of-frame (SoF), Carrier-sense multiple access with collision detection (CSMA/CD), Universal Serial Bus Test and Measurement Class (USBTMC) AND how do I allow 2 level abbreviations Battery Charging (BC), communication channel (CC) Could you please help! Pain in Grief (PG) Carrier-sense multiple access with collision detection (CSMA/CD)";

const regex = new RegExp(text.match(/\([A-Z\/]+(?=\))/g).map(m =>
    m.split("").slice(1).map(i => i.replace(/\//g, "") + "\\S*").join("(?:\\s+(?:(?:and|in|with)\\s+)?|\\s*[-&]\\s*)")
        .concat("\\s*\\" + m + "\\)")
).join("|"), "gi");

let match;
while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
    console.log(`${regex.lastIndex - match[0].length}-${regex.lastIndex}: ${match[0]}`);
}
```

Comment: maybe put `?` if the max number of space is 1

Comment: Couldn't match start-of-frame (SOF) , start-of-frame (SoF), Carrier-sense multiple access with collision detection (CSMA/CD), Universal Serial Bus Test and Measurement Class (USBTMC) AND how do I allow 2 level abbreviations Battery Charging (BC), communication channel (CC) Could you please help!

Comment: @CodeGuy updated to cover `-` and ` and ` in between.

Comment: Thank you so much, Would it be possible for a more generic instead of allowing only **and** ? Sometimes there could be a way we have abbreviations like Pain in Grief (PG). Propably allow more general instead of listing each in our regex. I mean we can allow a general word in between... **Carrier-sense multiple access with collision detection (CSMA/CD)**

Answer (score 1):

You may use this pure regex to fix your match:

```
/\b(\w)[-'\w]*(?: (\w)(?=[^(]*\([^)]*\2)[-",\/\\*&'\w]*)*\s*\(\1[A-Z]+\)/g
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CRR5zi/10)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b(\w)[-'\w]*` Match a single word and capture first letter in group #1
- `(\w)(?=[^(]*\([^)]*\2)`: Match a word char and capture in group #2 as long as that letter is present in next `(...)`
- `[-",\/\\*&'\w]*`: Match 0 of more allowed characters part of same word
- `(?: (\w)(?=[^(]*\([^)]*\2)[-",\/\\*&'\w]*)*`: Match 0 or of such words separated by a single space
- `\s*` match optional whitespace before `(...)`
- `(\1[A-Z]+\)`: Match `cp`

Comment: What about the case `standard that establishes specifications cables (SC)` in the example? Obviously it should skip `standard that establishes`.

Comment: standard that establishes @TimTimWong how to do that?

Comment: @CodeGuy You'll need to generate the RegEx dynamically in JavaScript after an initial matching phase.

Comment: @anubhava that will not match abbr such as SSL or anything that repeats the first initial

Comment: @anubhava `secure socket layer (SSL)` becomes only `socket layer (SSL)` in your demo 2.

Comment: @TimTimWong I have provided a pure regex based solution now.

Comment: @anubhava very impressive. didn't think of using lookahead with repeating capture group.

Comment: @anubhava nevertheless, `secure socket layer (SL)` and `secure socket layer (SAAAL)` also match in your latest edit.